# Not getting into GRUB (no sign of Ubuntu) after running Boot-Repair to fix grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I've had a dual boot of  Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) on my notebook for quite a while and today when I started it I got into grub rescue instead of the regular GRUB menu and I couldn't boot either of my 2 operating systems.

I came across boot-repair in the help section of ubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). So I created a live-usb of Ubuntu 12.10 and followed the instruction to get boot-repair and run it and it ran successfully and told me to reboot.

After doing this boot-repair, whenever I start my notebook I don't get into GRUB; my Windows 7 just boots automatically, so I don't know how to get on my Ubuntu anymore.

Part of the boot-repair log*:

```
=> Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.07 2013-07-25
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 58112 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the /uui 
                       directory. No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi.signed 
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi
```

---

*<sub>editor's note: pastie link was gone; the above was copied from the answer to clarify the question.</sub>

Comment: could you post the boot-repair log?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, forgot to add that. Here it is:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6997243/

Answer (score 3):

```
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.07 2013-07-25
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 58112 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the /uui 
                       directory. No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi.signed 
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi
```

The boot-repair log clearly shows that there is no sign of installed Ubuntu on your HDD. Maybe your Ubuntu partition got formatted or something else. So please try to reinstall Ubuntu on a separate partition wherever you want.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Wow... that's really strange... I guess I could just format the whole pc and reinstall windows and linux, but is there any way I can get a hand on the files that were on my Ubuntu?

I've done this before on windows but I tried running the program again but it cant find the files now because the partition was a linux partition.